# JSON Parse showing correctly in console but returning undefined in the code

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, tags

i'm trying to parse a json file and change the h1 innerHTML of a div into what the json file returns

This is my code

```
let ParsedData = {};

function FetchJSON(path){
    fetch(path)
        .then(function(resp)    {
            return resp.json();
        })
        .then(function(data)    {
            console.log(data)
            ParsedData = data;
        }
    );
}

function ClonePost(data){
    const Postlist = document.getElementById('PostList')
    const ItemToCopy = Postlist.querySelector('#Post')

    Item = ItemToCopy;

    Item.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = ParsedData[0];

    Postlist.appendChild(Item.cloneNode(true));
}

ClonePost(FetchJSON(/*Filepath*/));
```

the code returns data correctly in the console, but the h1 innerHTML becomes "Undefined" how can i fix this?

Comment: Please share the contents in `ParsedData`

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: You need to do like this:

`FetchJSON(/*Filepath*/).then(() => ClonePost())` because `FetchJSON()` will return a promise and control will go immediately to `ClonePost()` and `ParsedData` may not be loaded by the time you update the desired `innerHTML`.

Other comments: 1) the argument `data` to `ClonePost(data)` is not doing anything useful, and 2) please research Javascript naming conventions followed by the community.